# What is the proper form of "In the beginning" for this sentence?

Tags: syntax, transcription

Okay, so I fixed my first problem. Now, I have to find the proper form of "in the beginning." Should it be はじめに、すなおだった (hajime ni, sunaodatta,) or はじめは、すなおだった (hajime wa, sunaodatta?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sentence はじめは  ("at first", "in the beginning") is correct. This は is contrastive, and can be used with another subject marked with は (e.g., はじめは彼は素直だった). はじめに means "first (of all)", "at the beginning (of a month, etc)", "Introduction/Preface (chapter title)" and so on.

Comment: Thank you. And one more thing. Does the sentence translate to, "In the beginning, I was upfront?" I have a feeling that sunaodatta changes with context.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK Without proper context, it's impossible to say yes or no. There are many similar words such as 素直, 正直, 率直, *docile*, *honest*, *obedient*, *straightforward* and so on. I don't know in which context you want to use this sentence.

Comment: I'm desiring to use it for upfront.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK I know. And I said without proper context, it's impossible to say yes or no. [*Upfront* has many possible translations](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=upfront&ref=sa) and no one knows in what kind of context you want to say *upfront*.

Comment: I understand and your help is appreciated. Thank you.